# Firebase Cloud function-Get document snapshot field which is the URL of a file in firebase storage and delete the file from firebase storage - js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I want to retrieve the field value from a document snapshot which is the URL of a file in firebase storage and delete the file from firebase storage also the firestore document if the time of creation of the doc is before 24 hrs.

I am able to delete expired firestore documents successfully with the code below:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { firestore } = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.removeExpiredDocuments = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 1 hours").onRun(async (context) => {
  const db = admin.firestore();
  const now = firestore.Timestamp.now();
  const ts = firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(now.toMillis() - 86400000); // 24 hours in milliseconds = 86400000

  const snapshots = await db.collection("photos").where("timestamp", "<", ts).get();
  let promises = [];
  snapshots.forEach((snap) => {
    promises.push(snap.ref.delete());
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
});
```

but I don't know how to retrieve the field value(URL of file) from the document snapshot within the forEach block and delete the file from firebase storage.

Here's the firestore database:

[image]

The field value of photourl is to be retreived.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I think code look like :

```
//some code ....
    snap.docs.map((doc) => {
    if (doc.exist) {
       var url = doc.data().photourl;
       //do something logic call to firestorage and deleted data base on url get 
       //write logic deleted url firebase after deleted success firestorage           
    }

  });
```